# Translator package does not provide translation in language as expected

Tags: beamer, translator

I am trying to define some new `keys` in `translator` to be used with my own theme, for things like a copyright notice and such. However it seems I am doing something wrong and I am looking for support. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[german]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-German.dict}
\ProvidesDictionary{test}{German}
\providetranslation{test}{German}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-English.dict}
    \ProvidesDictionary{test}{English}
    \providetranslation{test}{English}
\end{filecontents*}

\usedictionary{test}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\translate{test}

\translate{author}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I expected that the use of `\translate{test}` should show *German* and `\translate{author}` should show *Autor*, however it remains being written in English. At least it seems `translator` loads my dictionary, but why doesn't it load the German dictionary and use it?

Comment: Not at pc so cannot test. But don't you need something like babel to specify which language you're using?

Comment: Actually that does the trick, but it is more tricky than that: A simple `\usepackage{babel}` is enough to give the correct translation!

Comment: @daleif, you fixed my issue, do you want to make it an answer, so I can accept it? I am now struggling with the next issue, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552303/how-can-i-suppress-an-error-when-there-is-no-language-given-for-babel-and-fall-b