# How can I suppress an error when there is no language given for babel and fall back to english?

Tags: beamer, babel

After understanding what was my mistake with `translator` ([Translator package does not provide translation in language as expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552087/translator-package-does-not-provide-translation-in-language-as-expected)), I tried to load `babel` in my theme. This works great, however if the user does not explicitly select a language, babel is angry with me: `! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.`

Only if you explicitly select `english`, `german` or whatever, it works.

The MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{beamerthemeBabelDep.sty}
\RequirePackage{translator,babel}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-German.dict}
    \ProvidesDictionary{test}{German}
    \providetranslation{test}{German}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test-English.dict}
    \ProvidesDictionary{test}{English}
    \providetranslation{test}{English}
\end{filecontents*}

\usetheme{BabelDep}
\usedictionary{test}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \translate{test}
    
    \translate{author}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that babel is loaded with `english` as a fallback language, if the user did not request one in the list of options to `beamer`?

Comment: Which `babel` version are you using?

Comment: My log says `Babel <3.12>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to update `babel` (current version is 3.45). Currently it defaults to `nil`, which, as its name implies, changes nothing at all. In practice, this preserves the class language (English, in the standard classes). Alternatively, you can pass any option to `babel` with something like:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
```

(See the manual.)